# What does meditatively mean?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

What does "meditatively" mean? I found a sentence that goes like:

> He scratched his beard meditatively.

And

> He looked at me meditatively.

Comment: You could have easily answered your own question with the use of a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two definitions of "meditative"

> 1: marked by or conducive to meditation

> 2: disposed or given to meditation

"He scratched his beard meditatively" probably suggests how the person is in deep thought and is thinking about something in peace (meditatively), and therefore scratches his beard.

"He looked at me meditatively" probably suggests how the person is looking at you curiously or deep in thought e.g. whether to select you for a competition (only an example) in a meditative state (peaceful again)

Source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meditative)